# How do I get the height of an element after it is populated by angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, http, angularjs

I'm doing a `$http.get` to get json data, which is then used to populate the views with something like

```
$scope.getIdeas = function() {
  $http.get(ideasUrl)
    .success(function(data) {
      $scope.ideas = data;
      console.log($(".ideas-list").height()); // No height yet =(
    })
};
```

This then populates the view

```
<ul ng-cloak class="ideas-list" ng-init="getIdeas()">
  <li class="idea"
    ng-repeat="idea in ideas"
    >{{idea.text}}</li>
</ul>
```

However, on the `success` call, the `.ideas-list` doesn't have a height yet. Where would I be able to get the populated view height? Is there an event I can hook into?

Comment: -1 for mixing jQuery with Angular, making the question and answer more than a little misleading. Best practice for Angular is to not mix jQuery with it as it's antithetical to the Angular model and it's "not the Angular way" - reason being that jQuery works on the DOM directly which conflicts with the fact that in Angular the DOM is generated by a render engine which can conflict (often in bad/bizarre/unpredictable ways). I'd like to see a solution in pure Angular rather than mixed Angular/jQuery.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `setTimeout` (or preferably the `$timeout` service) so that Angular can change the dom before you check the height:

```js
$scope.getIdeas = function() {
  $http.get(ideasUrl)
    .success(function(data) {
      $scope.ideas = data;
      $timeout(function(){
        console.log($(".ideas-list").height());
      });
  })
};
```

Comment: Great, that works! It's very unintuitive though. How does angular even know the right timeout?

Comment: When you add data to the $scope the dom doesn't get updated before Angular detects this change and rebuilds the dom. Since the success callback is wrapped in an `$apply` the change will happen in the same thread of execution. That's why you can just add a `setTimeout` with no delay (it's like you tell the program to get done with everything that it's about to do first, then execute the timeout callback function).

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on mobile, maybe the threads work differently there?

Comment: Try adding a small delay: `$timeout(function(){
        console.log($(".ideas-list").height());
      },100);`

Comment: Turns out you were still right (without the delay). It was `.height()` that was being calculated incorrectly on mobile. Using `height = data.length * $(".ideas-list").outerHeight();` fixed it.